# Game Center Invitation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using Game Kit and I want to submit a score on Game Center. I did that but now I want to invite friends. How do I invite my friends and how do I see my friend's score? This code is for show leaderboard:

```
  - (IBAction) showLeaderboard
  {
     GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
     if (leaderboardController != NULL) 
     {
        leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self; 
        [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general functions needed for friend interaction in Game Center can be found in [Working with Players in Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6).

There is even a section on inviting friends under [Allowing the Local Player to Invite Other Players to Be Friends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW16):

```
- (void) inviteFriends: (NSArray*) identifiers
{
    GKFriendRequestComposeViewController *friendRequestViewController = [[GKFriendRequestComposeViewController alloc] init];
    friendRequestViewController.composeViewDelegate = self;
    if (identifiers)
    {
        [friendRequestViewController addRecipientsWithPlayerIDs: identifiers];
    }
    [self presentViewController: friendRequestViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
    [friendRequestViewController release];
}
```